# jquery mobile how to disable only one choice of radiobutton group

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button

Is there any way to disable only one choice of radiobutton group in jquery mobile 1.1?

how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You know what `radio input` shall be disabled, You need to find the container `div` added by JQM:

```
$("#my-radio-input").closest("div.ui-radio").addClass("ui-disabled");
```